# Target.Name.Name Error using Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: vba, excel

All,

Are there any differences between the `Target` range passed into the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event than the `Target` range passed into the `Worksheet_Change` event? 
This question seems ridiculous, but I cannot seem to get the `Target.name.name` from the `SelectionChange` `Target` range, but I can get the `Target.name.name` from the `Change` `Target` range for the same cell in question.

I have tried unprotecting the sheet with the `userinterfaceonly` parameter set to true, I have tried completely unprotecting the sheet, but have not seen anything different.

NOTES: The `SelectionChange` `Target` range looks valid, I can get other properties like `Target.row` or `Target.address` from the parameter passed into the event, just not the name.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The cell in question is a merged cell, if that makes any difference.

Comment: In `SelectionChange` the `Target` is the cell you just selected; in `Change` it's the one you just changed - typically not the same as the one that's active now.

Comment: @Rory That is a good distinction. I knew that when testing however, so my question still stands.

Comment: But that's what you asked? You'd get an error if you didn't select a named range.

Comment: @Rory I am asking what the differences are in the range that is passed into the two events. Lets say that I have given merged cell `A1:B2` the name "product_lot_number". To test the `SelectionChange`, I clicked on cell `A1:B2` when a different cell was selected. To test the `Change` event, I typed "123" into cell `A1:B2`. Both times the `Target` range in question was `A1:B2`.

Comment: There is no difference then. Does the cursor move to a different cell after you change A1? If so, the Selectionchange event will likely error then.

Comment: @Rory Perplexing, isn't it! It is true that the `SelectionChange` event errors when the selection moves to another cell after submission, but I am not concerned with that, I can add error handling for that. Something is different between the two, I am still having the error of not being able to get the `target.name.name` value from the `SelectionChange` event when I am able to get it just fine from the `Worksheet_Change` event. I just can't tell what is causing the problem yet. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Ah, missed the merged cells bit on my phone. The `SelectionChange` target is the whole range you selected, just as if you change multiple cells at once, `Target` for the Change event is all those cells. But merged cells only treat the first cell as being changed, even though it treats all of them as selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged cells do bad things to VBA code. You can figure them out, they're just not very intuitive.  For your case, you need

```
Debug.Print Target.Cells(1).Name.Name
```

Generally when you get an error with a merged cell, you either need `.Cells(1)` or `.MergeArea`, but I never know which one so I try them both.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what it was. The `Worksheet_Change` `Target` range was only the first cell of that merged range, whereas `Worksheet_SelectionChange` was passing in the whole merged range in the `Target` parameter. Strange stuff.

Comment: Interesting. In Excel 2010 I get the same error for both Change and SelectionChange.

Comment: You should get double credit, because the `.MergeArea` has saved my skin a couple of times now on different issues!

Answer (score -1):

The problem may also be that using `Target.Name` supposes that `Target` has a name. However, if you click on a cell that has no name, `Target.Name` returns an error.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but the problem wasn't with the name, because `Worksheet_Change` wasn't giving me any problems but `Worksheet_SelectionChange` was giving me problems. Same cell.